# Traveling inside Schengen state for work - no visa

Tags: schengen, work, visa-expiration, permits

I have applied for a temporary permit (Poland) 8 months ago and I'm still waiting. I have a stamp in my passport stating that I have applied and waiting for the result, but it is written in Polish. The problem is that my visa is running out and I must travel to another Schengen state for work after my visa expires. I don't go through immigration when travelling within Schengen states, but if my passport gets checked outside Poland,  I might be an 'illegal immigrant' instantly.

What do I do here?

Comment: Are you traveling for business or are you moving to work in another country?

Comment: I don't see any obvious solution. You're presumably supposed to wait for a proper Polish (temporary) residence permit before travelling to other places in the Schengen area. Maybe ask the Polish authorities to extend the validity of their visa?